# Altium error message: Net(s) Not Found in Differential Pair

Tags: pcb-design, altium

When I try to validate changes from my project, I get this error message:

> Net(s) Not Found in Differential Pair PA_D : Positive Net [PA_D_P] & Negative Net [PA_D_N] in current PCB document

[image: snippet from schematic diagram]

Comment: Are there other names assigned to these nets on some other sheet?

Comment: @ThePhoton, yes I am Using Hierarchical Design .

Comment: Sadly, not all features of Altium work well when used together. I'd recommend not labelling signals differently in different sheets. Either remove the labels from the other sheets, or be sure to label them the same in all sheets.

Answer (score 1):

In comments you said you have different labels on these nets on a different sheet.

Probably, Altium has chosen to use those other labels for the overall netlist, so if they don't have the correct _N and _P endings, Altium won't be able to define these nets as a differential pair.

I'd recommend not labeling signals differently in different sheets. Either remove the labels from the other sheets, or be sure to label them the same in all sheets.